# Translation Table, Replace String and Select proper Row

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, one with strings, that need to be checked for certain strings that need to be replaced. The second table contains two columns, one with strings to be searched and one with the strings to be replaced - to be short a translation table:

```
|Name     |Age|           |Short|Long  |
---------------           ------------
|Mr. Smith|23 |           |Mr.  |Mister|
|Ms. Anna |78 |           |Ms.  |Misses|
|Jack Jr. |12 |           |Jr.  |Junior|
|Mister A |23 |           --------------
|John     |41 |
---------------
```

I think I have to do a Cross-Join and select distinct values.

But now I have both rows, the ones with Mr. and Mister, how do I select only the ones with "Mister":

```
[I need this table]             [but this is the result]
|Name         |Age|             |Name         |Age|     
-------------------             -------------------     
|Mister Smith |23 |             |Mr. Smith    |23 |     
|Misses Anna  |78 |             |Mister Smith |23 |
|Jack Junior  |12 |             |Ms. Anna     |78 | 
|Mister A     |23 |             |Misses Anna  |78 | 
|John         |41 |             |Jack Jr.     |12 | 
-------------------             |Jack Junior  |12 | 
                                |Mister A     |23 |
                                |John         |41 | 
                                -------------------
```

I can't do an "Except" because the table contains also rows, that don't need to be translated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the maximum number of words can be present in `name` field?

Comment: Can you show please query with which you receive that result?

Comment: select distinct ifnull(replace(t1.name,t2.short_name,t2.long_name),t1.name), t1.age from t1 cross join t2;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following sql query:

```
select ifnull(replace(t1.name,t2.short_name,t2.long_name),t1.name) as name,
t1.age

from
t1
left join t2
on t2.short_name=if(instr(t1.name,t2.short_name)>0,t2.short_name,t1.name)
```

Note: Use `UPPER` or `LOWER` function for case-mismatch. Use `TRIM` function for space issue.

Verify result at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6b238/5

Comment: @G-M : what is the difference in edited sample.? Does this answer resolve your issue.? If not, then specify what issue you found in the output.

Comment: Ok sorry your solution is working, but could you explain it a little? I understand that if the replacement fails, it takes the t1.name, but I don't quite understand the Left-Join condition `t2.short_name=if(instr(t1.name,t2.short_name)>0,t2.short_name,t1.name)` because `t2.short_name = t1.name` will never be `true` `if instr()<0`

Comment: @G-M : Yes, `t2.short_name = t1.name` is always false condition. I needed this in order to keep data where no matching found.

Comment: why are you using the `if(instr())` and not the same condition as above with `ifnull(replace())`, is there a reason? Many thanks for your replies!

Comment: @G-M : In `on-clause`, I need to check existence of a substring in a string. On the other hand, in `select`, I need to replace the substring by another string. `ifnull` is used for correct `name` where substitution is not required.